# Solve the inequality for real $\Bbb R$ & also in $\Bbb N$

Tags: inequality

Solve in Real Number $\Bbb R$ 
 and Natural Number $\Bbb N$,

$\frac x 2 + 1 ≤ 2x - 5 < x $

*My attempt:*

$\frac x 2 + 1 ≤ 2x - 5 < x $

$\implies \frac x 2 + 1 - 1 ≤ 2x - 5 -1 < x - 1$

$\implies \frac x 2  ≤ 2x - 6 < x - 1$

$\implies 2 \times \left(\frac x 2  ≤ 2x - 6 < x - 1\right)$

$\implies x  ≤ 4x - 12 < 2x - 2$

Removing $x$ from 3 sides,

$\implies 0  ≤ 3x - 12 < x - 2$

This is where I am stuck.

After this I am unable to solve because whatever addition/subtraction for $x$ I do, it transfers to opposite end, hence at the end two $x$'s are there at different sides of inequality sign .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the parts of the inequality separately.

$$3x-12\geq 0 \implies 3x\geq 12 \implies x\geq 4$$

$$x-2 > 3x-12 \implies 2x < 10 \implies x<5$$

Thus, $$5> x \geq 4$$

For real solutions, $$x \in [4,5)$$
For natural number solutions, $x=4$ as it is the only natural number in this interval.

Comment: I was not sure of solving by parts previously, but now i am clear. Thanks !